# toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers: is not called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I'm trying to make selectable NSToolbarItems. I've connected everything correctly in IB, but `toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers:` is not working. It doesn't get called. The delegate is the File's Owner (subclass of NSWindowController), and the toolbar is in a sheet. Here's my code:

```
// TOOLBAR DLGT
- (NSArray *)toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar {
  NSLog(@"Foo");
  NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (NSToolbarItem *item in [toolbar items]) {
    [arr addObject:[item itemIdentifier]];
  }
  return [arr autorelease];
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Can you help me please?

---

**No, I don't want to use BWToolkit.**

Comment: As an aside, unless you're planning to add a condition inside that loop later, you can replace the whole loop and mutable array with `return [[toolbar items] valueForKey:@"itemIdentifier"];`. NSArray implements `valueForKey:` by returning an array of every contained object's value for the key.

Answer (score 0):

Are you *positive* the toolbar's delegate outlet points to the class (or instance thereof) you think it does? Are any other NSToolbar delegate methods called there (easy enough to test)?